# PhoneGap for Android does not accept the 9 key

Tags: android, cordova

I have a strange problem in my PhoneGap-based android app.  On certain screens, the 
number 9 key is completely ignored.  This happens on all my Android 
2.X devices.  I have tried with previous versions of PG and found that 
the problem first occurred in v1.2.

Here is the code to a sample index.html file that should reproduce the issue.  On both Android 2.2 and 2.3, the text boxes labeled as "broken" do not accept the number 9 as input.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
        body
        {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            font-size:20px;
        }

        input
        {
            height:20px;
        }

        #container_second
        {
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            width:100%;
            height:150px;
        }

        #container_second div
        {
            left: -2000px;
            position: absolute;
            -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 2000, 0);
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br />
        <div id="container_first">
            <div>
                Working Text: <br /><input type="text" /><br /><br />
                Working Tel: <br /><input type="tel" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <br /><br />

        <div id="container_second">
            <div>
                Broken Text: <br /><input type="text" /><br /><br />
                Broken Tel: <br /><input type="tel" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it seems the combination of the css is causing some issue. if you remove all the above css or just `overflow:hidden` then it works as expected

Comment: Yes, but the css is there as a way to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It seems that there are multiple ways to cause this issue to happen.  Using this particular CSS is just one way.  I included it exactly like this in the hope that it would help someone familiar with the PhoneGap source code to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It might be related to [this issue](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/ede2f70be3323e34).  For some reason PhoneGap is calling setNavDump on the web view's WebSettings.  setNavDump is an obsolete method according to the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setNavDump%28boolean%29) so you should be fine if you disable it.

One way to do it is by overriding the init method in your class that extends DroidGap

```
    @Override
public void init() {
    super.init();       
    this.appView.getSettings().setNavDump(false);
}
```

---

If that doesn't work, try adding it after the `loadUrl` call in the existing `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //... snip ...
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 12000);
    this.appView.getSettings().setNavDump(false);
    //... snip ...
}
```

Comment: My PhoneGap/Cordova 1.7 app was crashing on the Nexus 7 whenever I entered the number 7 on the soft keyboard, and this fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  Turns out that you need to specify the Android SDK version via the API number in the config.xml file

add:
    `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />`

Comment: I believe that config.xml is only for PhoneGap Build.  I am building in Eclipse so I do not have that file.  I have the minSdkVersion specified in AndroidManifest.xml and it still does not work correctly.<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a phonegap application in eclipse(for android). I had the same problem. When i pressed on 7, the application stopped and when i press on 9, the application do nothing in the text area components. It was also a problem appears on android versions 2.2 & 2.3.3. In the layout, there were a structure such as frame->frame->linear layout. And then i removed both of the frames. I just used linear layout and then the problem solved. I can press on 7 & 9 and there is no problem in the application. I mean, you should check for the unused layout components.