# Numeric 9 on Android 2.X

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, html, cordova

i've got a Problem with my Phone.
I'm currently programing an Android App with a Registration Field, in this Field i can't type in the Number 9. My App is using Phonegap, jQuery and jQtouch. Everything is working fine except for this error.

The problem only occurs on Android 2.X.

Any suggestion why i can't type in a 9?

Comment: You're going to need to give us more to go on. Like some code. Or better yet a live example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.  To fix it you will need to put the following line in your phonegap init function:

this.appView.getSettings().setNavDump(false);

Here is a link to my original question and the more detailed answer:

[PhoneGap for Android does not accept the 9 key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781657/phonegap-for-android-does-not-accept-the-9-key)

Answer (score -1):

There is possible to define in the layout xml file which digits are allowed to type into an input field ([take a look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adigits)) - maybe something's bugged so it allows all digits except the number 9?

For example:

```
<EditText
   android:digits="1" />
```

Will create an input field which only accepts the number "1" entered.

This seems like it could be a likely cause, but it's not really easy to say for sure before you supply some code to look at.