# PhoneGap Android App Software Keyboard Click Causes App to Crash

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard, hybrid

I have a hybrid application developed using jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap. One of our users who has a Nexus 7 Tablet is facing an issue - when the focus is in a text box and if the 7 key is pressed application closes on its own.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior? Is there a fix or a way to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: It seems like the issue is limited to Jellybean 4.1.x - has anyone else seen this issue? Pressing the 7 key causes the app to crash or hang.

Comment: Found the solution to this issue here -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781657/phonegap-for-android-does-not-accept-the-9-key

 @Override
public void init() {
    super.init();       
    this.appView.getSettings().setNavDump(false);
}