# On Clicking number seven or some special chars app is getting exit

Tags: android, cordova

I had develop an app in android phone gap the app is working fine normally , but when I enter 7 in the text field the app is getting exit (force close with out any dialog).
this problem is only arising in android 4.2 version, and my phonegap version is 1.7,

if found to add

```
appView.getSettings().setNavDump(true);
```

but no difference in my nexus

My logcat is

```
    02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):       RenderBlock {DIV} at (0,0) size 320x0
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554): layer at (0,0) size 320x460
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):   RenderBlock (positioned) {DIV} at (0,0) size 320x460
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554): layer at (0,0) size 320x460
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):   RenderBlock (positioned) zI: 1 {DIV} at (0,0) size 320x460
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554): layer at (0,0) size 320x460
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):   RenderBlock (positioned) zI: 2 {DIV} at (0,0) size 320x460
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):     RenderBlock {FORM} at (0,0) size 320x0
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):       RenderBlock (floating) {SECTION} at (0,0) size 320x435
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):         RenderBlock (floating) {DIV} at (0,85) size 320x80
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):           RenderText {#text} at (0,0) size 4x15
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):             text run at (0,0) width 4: " "
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):         RenderBlock (floating) {DIV} at (22,200) size 275x225
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):           RenderBlock {H3} at (0,0) size 275x16 [color=#A7A7A7]
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):             RenderText {#text} at (115,0) size 45x16
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):               text run at (115,0) width 45: "SIGN IN"
02-27 17:45:15.796: D/webcoreglue(3554):           RenderTextControl {INPUT} at 
02-27 17:45:15.796: A/libc(3554): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 3569 (WebViewCoreThre)
```

Comment: The most possible reason I can think of is that **KEYPAD_7** is a shortcut for switching to **LANDSCAPE MODE**. Maybe your app doesnt supports different modes. It would be helpfull if you could post the logcat stack trace.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781657/phonegap-for-android-does-not-accept-the-9-key

Comment: I dont know why the exception is but the solution is  appView.getSettings().setNavDump(false);  there i had given true